# Python websocket library

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to make a webpage that uses websockets to connect to a Python script. I'm currently using the websocket_server library which works fine when viewing the page from my computer or phone browser but doesn't work when viewing on my TV.

I've noticed the request sent from my TV is a bit different from other browsers. The request from my computer looks like:

```
b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.0.153:5001\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nOrigin: http://192.168.0.153:5555\r\nSec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\nSec-WebSocket-Key: /1Tw64u1Zd5SSvJd56hQeA==\r\nSec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits\r\n\r\n'
```

and from the TV:

```
b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nUpgrade: WebSocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nHost: 192.168.0.153:5001\r\nOrigin: http://192.168.0.153:5555\r\nSec-WebSocket-Key1: 1_7236`8 \ 86d[1 w?0\r\nSec-WebSocket-Key2: W 38 0 5o P 4 7]0 7 50\r\n\r\n\xdb{x\x9f\xa3\x12\!'
```

It has 2 Sec-WebSocket-Key sections and neither are base64 encoded. Is this an older version of the websocket protocol or is the implementation in the TV just borked? If it is an older version, are their any Python libraries that support it or perhaps some kind of work around?

Thanks.

edit:

Python version 3.6

The TV is an LG 47lm6200-ue, I can't find any info about the OS it uses or anything about the browser it's using. It's from 2012 so I believe it's before LG switched to webOS.

I'm creating the socket in JavaScript by doing:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.0.153:5001/");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on TV platform? python version? websocket request sending code snippet?

Comment: IIRC, the old hixie versions had Sec-WebSocket-Key and Sec-WebSocketKey2 that look like this, but at some point before the RFC it was replaced with the single base64 key that gets hashed with some fixed constant GUID, or something like that.

Comment: You'll need to look at the actual specs to figure out which version this is, and then look for a library that supports that version. For the first part, I think Wikipedia's page on websockets has a nice chart of all the protocol versions with links to the specs for them. For the second—there are good resources for asking for library recommendations, but StackOverflow isn't one of them. I'd suggest going to python.org's Community section, looking for a mailing list or something else that seems relevant, and trying the main python-list or the IRC channel if nothing does.